# Blogs are repeating on all category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am trying to create custom template for blog category page with pagination but problem is when i go to page number 2, 3 it shows same blogs which are present on page number 1.

i tried below code :

```
 <?php
$category       = get_the_category();
$category_ID    = $category[0]->term_id;
$title    = get_the_title();
$content  = get_the_content();
get_header(); 

?>
<section class="service_wrp">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="wh-service-heading"> <?php single_cat_title(); ?> </h1>
            <div class="middle-nav">
                <p id="breadcrumbs">
                    <span>
                        <span>
                            <?php
                                if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
                                    yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');
                                }
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9"><!--left content-->
                <?php

                        $args = array( 'cat' => $category_ID,'orderby'=> 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ); 

                        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                        // echo "<pre>"; print_r($my_query); die;

                        if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 

                           while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 

                                $post           = get_post();

                                $title          = get_the_title();
                                $title          = isset( $title ) ? $title : '';

                                $thumb_url      = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
                                if($thumb_url==""){
                                  $thumb_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/images/blog_logo.jpg";
                                }                                                                   

                                $post_link      = get_permalink();

                                $post_date      = get_the_date('d-M-Y');

                                $arrPostDate    = explode('-', $post_date);

                                $totalComments  = wp_count_comments( $post->ID );

                            ?>
                            <div class="blogs-wrp"><!--blog 1-->
                                <div class="left-blog">
                                    <div class="blogs-date">
                                        <span><?php echo  $arrPostDate[0];?></span>
                                        <span><?php echo  $arrPostDate[1];?></span>
                                        <span><?php echo  $arrPostDate[2];?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="social-icons">
                                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" onclick="share_fb('<?php echo $post_link; ?>');"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>

                                         <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" onclick="share_tw('<?php echo $post_link; ?>');"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="blogs-post blog-list">
                                    <div class="full-width">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $thumb_url;?>" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <h4><a href="<?php echo $post_link;?>"><b><?php echo strtoupper($title);?></b></a></h4>
                                    <p><?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                    <div class="post-meta">
                                        <div class="blogs-read-more">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $post_link;?>">Read More...</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rigth-blog-meta">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>                    <?php echo $totalComments->approved; ?> <span class="comments">Comments</span></a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--blog 1-->
                             <?php
                           endwhile; 

                            the_posts_pagination( array(
                            'mid_size'  => 3,
                            'prev_text' => __( 'Previous Page', 'textdomain' ),
                            'next_text' => __( 'Next Page', 'textdomain' ),
                        ) );                                                       

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
                         endif;

                ?>


            </div><!--left content-->

            <div class="col-sm-3">
           <?php 
                 get_sidebar('bloglist');
           ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

    </div>

</div>
```

Reference url:- https://stageserver.co/twfh_dev/public/writers-resources/
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you did not define the `'posts_per_page' => 6,` and `'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' )` in your wp_query arguments. The first wil tell WP how many posts you would like to see on a page. The second will tell WP on which page you are.

In this way your $args would look like:

```
$args = array( 
'cat' => $category_ID,
'orderby'=> 'date', 
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => 6,
'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) 
);
```